# Shaders overriding other shaders

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Recently, I've been making a 3D game and I have been having trouble with making multiple shaders. I've researched this for a bit, and told that I had to use `gluseshader` or `shader.bind()` in my code, but the post processing shader overrides the cube shader.

Here is my code

```
package me.pale.main;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL13;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;

import me.pale.model.Voxel;
import me.pale.postprocess.FBO;
import me.pale.postprocess.PostProcessQuad;
import me.pale.shader.PostProcessShader;
import me.pale.shader.Shader;
import me.pale.texture.Tex;

public class BlockGame {
    
    float fac = 640;
    
    float t = 640;
    
    float u_Time = 0;
    
    Texture testtex;
    
    PostProcessShader postprocess;
    
    FBO fbo;
    
    float rot;
    
    PostProcessQuad ppq = new PostProcessQuad();
    
    Voxel test = new Voxel();
    
    // FBO fbo;
    
    public void window(String name, int width, int height) throws LWJGLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.create();
        
        fbo = new FBO(FBO.DEPTH_RENDER_BUFFER);
        postprocess = new PostProcessShader();
        Shader shader = new Shader();
        Tex testtex = new Tex();
        
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GLU.gluPerspective(90.0f, 1.333f, 0.1f, 650.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthMask(true);
        
        // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac);
        
        GL11.glTranslated(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
        
        // fbo.printAllThings();
        testtex.loadTexture("res/test.png");
        System.out.println(testtex.getTextureID());
        System.out.println(fbo.getColorTexture());

        System.out.println("PROGRAM ID FOR POST PROCESSING: " + postprocess.getProgID());
        System.out.println("PROGRAM ID FOR DEFAULT SHADER: " + shader.getProgID());
        
        float x = 0;
        
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            
            rot += 0.05f;
            // shader.start();
            shader.start(shader.getProgID());
            fbo.bindFBO();
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
            GL11.glPushMatrix();
                // shader.start(shader.getProgID());
                GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
                // GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
                GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
                GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, testtex.getTextureID());
                // GL20.glUniform1i(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "tex"), 1);
                GL11.glRotatef(rot += 0.01f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                test.draw();
                // GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
                // shader.halt();
            GL11.glPopMatrix();
            fbo.unbindFBO();
            
            // renderPP();
            // RENDER FBO QUAD
            GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            /* postprocess.start(postprocess.getProgID());
            
            GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "u_Time"), u_Time += 0.005f);
            
            if (fac < 0) {
                
                fac = 0;
                t = 0;
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
                
                // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac -= 0.25f);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), fac -= 0.8f);
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
                
                // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac += 0.25f);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), fac += 0.8f);
                
            }
            
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_R)) {
                
                fac = 1024;
                // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), 1024);
                GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), 640);
                
            }
            
            // GL20.glUniform1i(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "renderTex"), fbo.getColorTexture());
            // GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.getColorTexture());
            renderQuad();
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            postprocess.halt(); */
            
            postProcess();
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            
            // UPDATE DISPLAY
            Display.update();
            
        }
        
        fbo.wash();
        postprocess.wash();
        shader.wash();
        testtex.wash();
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        BlockGame bg = new BlockGame();
        bg.window("Game", 640, 480);
        
    }
    
    public void postProcess() {
        
        postprocess.start(postprocess.getProgID());
        
        GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "u_Time"), u_Time += 0.005f);
        
        if (fac < 0) {
            
            fac = 0;
            t = 0;
            
        }
        
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
            
            // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac -= 0.25f);
            GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), fac -= 0.8f);
            
        }
        
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
            
            // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), fac += 0.25f);
            GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), fac += 0.8f);
            
        }
        
        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_R)) {
            
            fac = 1024;
            // GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgID(), "fac"), 1024);
            GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "t"), 640);
            
        }
        
        // GL20.glUniform1i(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "renderTex"), fbo.getColorTexture());
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.getColorTexture());
        renderQuad();
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        postprocess.halt();
        
    }
    
    /* public void renderPP() {
        
        // postprocess.start();
        // GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.getColorTexture());
        
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        
        postprocess.start();
        
        GL20.glUniform1i(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(postprocess.getProgID(), "renderTex"), fbo.getColorTexture());
        // GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo.getColorTexture());
        
        renderQuad();
        postprocess.halt();
        
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        
    } */
    
    public void renderQuad() {
        
        // fbo.bindFBO();
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1, 1, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0);
        
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1, -1, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1, 1, 0);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1, -1, 0);
        
        GL11.glEnd();
        // fbo.unbindFBO();
        
    }
    
}
```

> The main problem I am having is using multiple shaders. I use one
> shader for the post processing (render FBO texture to quad), and a
> cube shader (the shader that textures the cube), but after I got FBOs
> working, shaders have been a hassle. Like the cube shader isn't
> working and the post-process shader is overriding it or overpowering
> it. It is also using a pixelized texcoord, one that I am not using at
> all in either shader files

This is currently what it is doing:

[image]

But its supposed to render a texture on it like this:

[image]

This is a workable solution, but the solution to this problem to make the texture render was to not start the cube shader `shader.start(shader.getProgID());`. I need shaders if I want to do some special effects per voxel group, and multiple shaders for other things in the future.

the cube shader, `shader.start(shader.getProgID());` is supposed to render a texture on the cube that is rendered on the fbo on the screen. The post processing shader, `postprocess.start(postprocess.getProgID());` is supposed to render the fbo to a texture, and put it on the quad, then renders the quad wrapped onto the screen. When I add `shader.start(shader.getProgID());`, it does not render the texture, but renders a pixelized texcoord, one that I am only using in the postprocess shader that is able to pixelize the fbo. When I specify no gl_FragColor in the cube shader (`shader.start(shader.getProgID());`), it still renders the pixelized texcoords. When I specify a `gl_FragColor`, it renders the pixelized texcoords, even if the `gl_FragColor` has a vec4 assigned to it, like `vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);`

It turns out that during debugging, it turns out that both the cube texture and the fbo texture have the same ID... How do I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not clear from reading this post what problem you need help solving. Is it the same one as [your previous post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/192702/39518)? If so, I'd recommend editing that one to clarify it, rather than deleting and re-posting a more vague version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having an enlightenment, there was an error in the shader code that the shader program wasn't catching because it was a vec2 method, but weird. Anyways, I got it working there was an error in shader code.